# Getting errors when i try to run dot net watch run on my Blazor project on .net5

Tags: c#, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

Hi just wanted to know if I have to do something differently.

as shown on tutorial on package manager console

I do pm > dir

then I get

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                   
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                   
d-----        02/08/2021     21:41                BattlesBlazor                                                          
-a----        02/08/2021     22:08           2581 .gitattributes                                                         
-a----        02/08/2021     22:08           6585 .gitignore                                                             
-a----        03/08/2021     10:28           2194 BattlesBlazor.sln
```

then when I run dotnet watch run I am getting the following error

```
dotnet : watch : Could not find a MSBuild project file in 'C:\Users\Desktop\Desktop\Deskto 2\DevProjects\BattlesBlazor'. 
Specify which project to use with the --project option.
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet watch run
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (watch : Could n...project option.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

not sure what is actually happening, any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit:  [The contents of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOh31.png)

Comment: Can you show the content of `BattlesBlazor.sln` file?

Comment: Arg, I miss the tag `blazor-webassembly`. I don't think it's possible to watch a wasm project. But you can watch the server part. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks now it is working - opens in Microsoft Edge and not in chrome but I think that's just because it has been set as the default browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to build a solution, this is why the following command works :

```
dotnet build
```

But it isn't possible to run a solution, because a solution can have multiple executable projects, or even none.

I don't think it's possible to watch a wasm project. But you can watch the server part.

To run, you can specify the project file like :

```
# Start the client without blocking the package console manager
start "" dotnet run --project BattlesBlazor\Client\BattlesBlazor.Client.csproj

# Start with diagnostic the server
dotnet watch run --project BattlesBlazor\Server\BattlesBlazor.Server.csproj
```

Comment: Hi so the dotnet build worked and the last two still giving the errors,

Comment: Do you see the .csrpoj file when you do `dir`?

Comment: nope i only get ```                                                                
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                   
d-----        02/08/2021     21:42                Client                                                                 
d-----        02/08/2021     21:42                Server                                                                 
d-----        02/08/2021     21:42                Shared                                                                 
PM>```

Comment: Can you show the content of `BattlesBlazor.sln` file?

Comment: Not sure if thats what you wanted - uploaded the image just now - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your working directory to where the .csproj is. In your case cd BattlesBlazor, then do a dotnet watch run.

Comment: not sure how to do this but will look into it